# Calculating the number of nodes in a tree when each level has diffrent number of nodes basing on minmal total number of nodes

Tags: c#, math, tree

I would like to write a function that calculates the following problem.

I have a tree that I know that has 4 levels with a different amount of nodes on each level.

1st 2 nodes
2nd 3 nodes each parent node
3rd 4 nodes each parent node
4th 1 node each parent node

How to calculate a total number of nodes that would be required to make a tree while keeping proportion if I would give a minimal amount of nodes as a parameter.

For example I give min node count as paramter 40

The minimal number of nodes for that tree to keep proportion would be around 56 (if I calculated correctly).

I assume that I can calculate the total number of nodes required by this equation

2x + 2x3y+ 2x3y4z + 2x3y4zt = number of nodes

Comment: Have I understood correctly, that if you would pass 1 as a parameter, the minimum amount of nodes is 24? First node has 2 children, each of them has 3 and each of them has 4 --> 2*3*4 = 24

Comment: No it should give 56.

Comment: Could you please tell us how your tree structure looks like in this format: `Level 1: X children, Level 2: Y children, Level 3: Z children, Level 4: n children`? Maybe this helps clarifing.

Comment: Level 1: 3 children, Level 2: 4 children, Level 3: 1 children

The first level will have 2 nodes with 3 children each node. I want to keep that proportion

Comment: This still leads me to this result: 2 (2 nodes on level 0) * 3 (3 children on level  1) * 4 (4 children on level 2) * 1 (1 child on level 3) = 24 nodes minimum, 48 if your parameter is between 25 and 48 etc.

Comment: 2 nodes + 6 nodes + 24 nodes + 24 nodes = 56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`private static int GetNodes(int min) => ((int)Math.Ceiling(min / 24.0)) * 24;`

You need to know how many times 24 fits in your number, so you divide this number by 24. Then you have to round up the result and multiply it with 24 to get your total nodes.

**Edit**

Some examples:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetNodes(1));    //  24
Console.WriteLine(GetNodes(23));   //  24
Console.WriteLine(GetNodes(24));   //  24
Console.WriteLine(GetNodes(25));   //  48
Console.WriteLine(GetNodes(60));   //  72
Console.WriteLine(GetNodes(100));  // 120
Console.WriteLine(GetNodes(150));  // 168
```

Comment: Your answer is ok but I think I would need 28 nodes :) not 24 thank you.